# How do I fix my interactive grocery list?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to make an interactive list of grocery items that I can add to and delete items as required. I've managed to get the JS code to add the item when submitted and delete the item when the cross is pressed, but if I delete an item and then try to add another, it adds the previously deleted items back in. How can I update the groceries array properly so this doesn't occur?

I've used onclick to delete at the moment and I'm not sure how to update the array correctly so it doesn't have the deleted elements.

HTML and JavaScript code:

```js
let htmlList = document.querySelector("#listItems");

let groceries = ["Apples", "Vegetables", "Butter", "Bread"];

function Groceryfunction() {

  let listGroc = groceries.map(user =>
    `<li>${user} <span class='close' onclick="this.parentNode.style.display='none'">\u00D7</span> </li>`
  );
  let finalList = listGroc.join('\n');

  htmlList.innerHTML = finalList;
}

Groceryfunction()

function addGrocery() {
  let groceryValue = document.getElementById('ItemAdded').value;

  if (groceryValue == '') {
    alert("Please enter an item!");
    document.getElementById("myForm").reset();
  } else {
    groceries.push(groceryValue);
    Groceryfunction(groceries)

    document.getElementById("myForm").reset();
    return false;
  }
}
```

```html
  <p>Groceries list:</p>
  <ul id="listItems"></ul>

  <form id="myForm">
    <label>Please enter the item you'd like to add to the list:</label>
    <input type="text" name='ItemAdded' id='ItemAdded'>
    <br>
    <br>
    <input type="submit" name="Submit" onclick="return addGrocery()">
  </form>
```

Comment: There is nothing with the id of `#listItems` in HTML!

Comment: Can you please provide us with a more complete html code and the delete function.

Comment: @Zerowiel I have updated the post

Comment: You could use `this.parentNode.remove();`, but a better technique would be to update the `groceries` array itself when the user removes an item. You might use the [`.splice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) method of the array, and you could determine what index of the array to splice by giving each grocery item a class (or a data-attribute) that matches its position in the array. (This is not the very best way, but it's one of the simplest, and much better than making your HTML responsible for remembering the state of your app.)

Answer (score 1):

This would be a shorter way of doing the same:

```js
const htmlList = document.querySelector("#listItems"),
      inp = document.querySelector('#ItemAdded'),
      btn = document.querySelector("button"),
      groceries = ["Apples", "Vegetables", "Butter", "Bread"],
      addItm=(itm)=>`<li>${itm} <span>\u00D7</span></li>`;

htmlList.innerHTML = groceries.map(addItm).join('\n');
htmlList.onclick=ev=>
  ev.target.tagName=="SPAN" && ev.target.parentNode.remove();

document.getElementById("myForm").onsubmit=()=>{
  if(inp.value>"") htmlList.innerHTML+=addItm(inp.value)
  return false;
}
btn.onclick=(ev)=>{ // collate a results array:
  let lst=[...htmlList.children].map(li=>li.childNodes[0].textContent.trim());
  console.log(lst)};
```

```html
<p>Groceries list:</p>
<ul id="listItems"></ul><button>checkout</button><br><br>

<form id="myForm">
  <label>Please enter the item you'd like to add to the list:</label>
  <input type="text" name='ItemAdded' id='ItemAdded'>
</form>
```